# Jenkins - JMeter Plugin - How to compare with Previous build in terms of Average Response time in Seconds

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, jmeter-plugins

I have Scheduled a JMeter Job in Jenkins. My Goal is to compare the result of the current test with previous build's result and provide the status accordingly. I have set the

Unstable % Range as  =  (-)1 to (+)1
Error % Range as  =  (-)5 to (+)5

My application's response time always have a variation of 1 second and it is an known factor

Since JMeter is returning Average Response time in milli seconds, Test is marked as failed or unstable as the difference in milli seconds is always high

Instead of comparing the response time in milli seconds, is it possible to convert the response time in Seconds and then perform an build comparison?

Comment: Were you able to find a plugin for this?